# How to put footnotes inside table inside minipages in the same page as the tables?

Tags: tables, footnotes, minipage

I have footnotes inside tables that are inside minipages (to put two tables in the same row in a two-column article).
I use

```
\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext[\value{footnote}]{ blah blah}


\begin{table*}[t]
\begin{minipage}[b]{.4\textwidth}
\centering
   \begin{tabular}{|l|l|} \hline
      XX& YY $^{\decimal{footnote}}$ \\\hline 
   \end{tabular}
   \caption{YYY)}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.65\textwidth}
   \begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline
      Example & Example2 \\\hline 
   \end{tabular}
   \caption{XXX)}
\end{minipage}
\end{table*}
```

But the problem is that the footnotes come a page before the table. Is there anyway to solve the issue.

Note that tablefootnote doesn't work here inside a minipage.

Comment: **threeparttable** or **threeparttablex** would be my first thought. Would be a lot easier if you'd post a complete example rather than a fragment. What does `\decimal` do?  You seem to have mismatched curly brackets in several places - the grouping looks very strange.

Comment: Please make your code snipped compilable so, that it will exhibit your problem.

Comment: I fixed the braces issue, \decimal is to use the footnote counter I suppose

Comment: However, your snepped is still not possible to copy and compile ... It missing: `\documentclass{...} \usepackage{.....}\begin{document} ... \end{document}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I found after a few hours playing with positioning the table and footnotes.

The footnote package has an environment called savenotes that allows to keep all footnotes and flush it at the end of the environment. So this is how I used it.

```
\begin{savenotes}
% put the table* here with footnotes that use \footnote command
% put some text here that you are sure the will fit in the page that the table will end up
\end{savenotes}
```

Note that footnote package is not coompatible with hyperref package. Thus you may want to pass [hyperfootnotes=false] option to it.